# Heroku Datsbase Migration Error (django.db.utils.DataError)

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have made a website using Django and hosted on Heroku. Everything was working fine until I try to alter my one of the column in the database. The thing is that I alter the column from max_length=1000 to max_length=60 but I forgot that I have entered value more than 60 so I got django.db.utils.DataError error that value is too long for 60.

For this problem solution, I refer one of the solutions available in StackOverflow to remove all the migrated file from its folder except **init**.py and then do fresh migration. So I tried that and I work with charm and I have changed the value so it could fit the max limit.

But now, when I try to create new column in database it says django.db.utils.ProgrammingError django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "column_name" of relation "table" does not exist

Actually, when I try to run my app on the local server it works fine and even it allows me to create a new column in my database but when I try to migrate it to Heroku database it shows django.db.utils.ProgrammingError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a backup from your server data. clean all the data on your database. delete all the migration.py files just as you read and then makemigrations and migrate again.